# Using environment variables in C code and Shell script

Tags: debian, environment, udev

I have written a udev rule in Debian which runs a shell script when a USB storage device is plugged into the system. The rule works perfectly fine.
The script in turn calls a few executable files which are stored in a specific path, 
For example, **/home/username/XYZtool/**

I want to store this path as an environment variable as follows,
**XYZpath=/home/username/XYZtool**

and call the executable files in the shell script with a **.$XYZpath/executable1**
command rather than giving the full absolute path like **./home/username/XYZtool/executable1**

However, when I use the environment variable my executable is not being called; but the executable is being called when I provide the full absolute path of the executable. 
Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

My script file looks like this

```
#!/bin/sh

./home/username/XYZtool/executable1        --> working

.$XYZpath/executable2                      --> not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a bit of investigation I have found a solution to this..

According to the udev rules,
(refer 'Environment interaction' section in http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html,)
the environment that udev sees will not be the same user environment as you get on the console.

Also, variables of the udev environment can be set in the rule itself; with the **ENV{some_var}="value"** option.

So, this solves the problem as the script files and the executable files that udev executes can see and use this environment variable!!